# Why is React Router Link rendering nothing?

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

I'm trying to make clickable links between pages on a front end. I suspect this is due to a recent update I made locally to npm. Everything works fine until I include Link from react-router-dom, then I get no rendering and receive the following errors:

```
 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'pathname')
    at resolveTo (index.tsx:1295)
    at index.tsx:619
    at mountMemo (react-dom.development.js:15846)
    at Object.useMemo (react-dom.development.js:16219)
    at useMemo (react.development.js:1532)
    at useResolvedPath (index.tsx:619)
    at useHref (index.tsx:361)
    at LinkWithRef (index.tsx:256)
    at renderWithHooks (react-dom.development.js:14985)
    at updateForwardRef (react-dom.development.js:17044)
```

```
The above error occurred in the <Link> component:

    at LinkWithRef (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:36439:5)
    at O (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:43031:6)
    at div
    at O (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:43031:6)
    at div
    at O (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:43031:6)
    at div
    at O (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:43031:6)
    at Navbar
    at HomePage
    at Routes (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:36924:5)
    at Router (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:36857:15)
    at BrowserRouter (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:36337:5)
    at App
```

Navbar.js

```
const Navbar = () => {
  return (
    <NavbarLink/>
  );
};
```

NavbarElements.js

```
import styled from "styled-components";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";

export const NavbarLink = styled(Link)`
`;
```

HomePage.js

```
import React from 'react'
import Navbar from '../components/Navbar/Navbar'

const HomePage = () => {
    return (
        <>
            <Navbar></Navbar>
        </>    
    )
}

export default HomePage
```

app.js

```
import {BrowserRouter as Router, Routes, Route} from 'react-router-dom'
import './App.css';
import HomePage from './pages/HomePage';

function App() {
  return (
    <Router>
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/" element={<HomePage/>} exact />
      </Routes>
    </Router>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: You don't have `to` in `<NavbarLink/>`..

Comment: The error is what it is. You can't leave pathname black in `<Link>` element. just add the `to` attribute to the Link tag

Comment: That was it! thank you, in the last version this was just a warning. That's what caused my confusion

Answer (score 0):

I believe it's because the Link component requires a `to` attribute:

So just do `<NavBarLink to="/somepage" />`

Let me know if that fixes the problem.